# What is the correct spelling for 'finash'/'feenash'/'phinash'/'pheenash'?

Tags: spelling-pronunciations

I have heard this word somewhere but am unsure how to spell it.

> He had a certain level of mastery of his pottery skills, he completed all his work with remarkable **finash/feenash/phinash/phines**

It might not be the best example of the usage of the word. But I have looked up online and the wordweb dictionary to no use. It's not 'finish'. It sounded like fee-na-sh.

Any idea? Or am I misunderstood and there isn't such a word?

Comment: "Panache", maybe?

Comment: Maybe *finesse*?

Comment: @jim I agree wholeheartedly. I was going to give that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word you are looking for is probably [finesse](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/finesse).

When referring to something creative or artistic, it means great skill and delicacy - getting all the 'fine' details right.